# copy source to destination if destination is n/a

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this simple data frame:

```
> dframe = data.frame(a=c(1,2,NA), b=c(11,NA,33))
> dframe
   a  b
1  1 11
2  2 NA
3 NA 33
```

My goal is to copy `a` to `b` for each row but, only if `b` is `NA`. So my final data should be this:

```
> dframe
   a  b
1  1 11
2  2 2
3 NA 33
```

I've tried this but it gives me an error:

```
> dframe[is.na(dframe$b), "b"] <- dframe[!is.na(dframe$a), "a"]
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(dframe$b), "b", value = c(1,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you've down voted? I can modify the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a logical index based on the NA value in 'b' ('i1').  Then assign the values in 'a' to 'b' that corresponds to  'i1'.

```
i1 <- is.na(dframe$b)
dframe$b[i1] <- dframe$a[i1]
dframe
#   a  b
#1  1 11
#2  2  2
#3 NA 33
```

---

In the OP's code, the indexing for lhs and rhs of `<-` is different as it is replacing non-NA elements in 'a' to NA elements of 'b'.  The problem is in the number of elements as mentioned in the error and it won't be replacing corresponding elements even if the number of NA and non-NA elements based on the index are the same.

```
sum(is.na(dframe$b))
#[1] 1
sum(!is.na(dframe$a))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dframe$b=ifelse(is.na(dframe$b),dframe$a,dframe$b))
```

Comment: why heve you deleted your `dplyr` answer? @others why have this been down voted?

Comment: It was not the best way to do it :)

Comment: can you be please explain the differences in answer? Thanks

Comment: Before I wrote `df %>% mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b),a,b)` but this can be achieved without `dplyr` as wrote in the answer. Maybe it's just my personal taste, but if something can be done with the same effort without loading any extra package, it is probably a better solution